# creating a horizontal colored strip using css

Tags: html, css

In my webpage  I need to put a horizontal colored strip of some width just beneath a Logo text.

I tried to use this css:

```
#colorstrip{
    width: 100%; height: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}
```

with this html:

```
<span id="logo"> My site</span>
<div id="colorstrip"/>
```

But it shows a white rectangle. How do I make it a filled one? Or do I have to use an image (may be a white square) and put it as background of the div with repeat?

Is using a div for showing this thin bar the correct way?
What do you advise?

Comment: What do you mean by a filled one? A gradient, a different colour or what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you want to fill it, use:

```
#colorstrip{
    width: 100%; height: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just apply the border to the bottom of the div:

```
#colorstrip{
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom:solid 2px red;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4dUD/

Then adjust `2px` to the height that you require

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the HTML `<hr>` tag? You can style this and it's probably more semantic.

```
<style type="text/css">
 hr {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 border:none;
 height:2px;
 }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `background-color:#fff` on your css?